# How to build data structure using nested calls to `map`

Tags: clojure

I want to build a sequence of maps (the data structure) using nested calls to map (the function). Here's what I'm doing

```
(defn point [x y]
  {:x-coord x
   :y-coord y})

(defn grid [rows columns]
  (mapcat 
    (fn [x] map
              (fn [y] (point x y))
              (range columns))
    (range rows)))
```

Which compiles fine, but doesn't work as I would expect. I expected that a call to grid would result in a sequence of maps:

```
user=>(grid 2 2)
({:x-coord 0, :y-coord 0} {:x-coord 0, :y-coord 1} {:x-coord 1, :y-coord 0} {:x-coord 1, :y-coord 1})
```

But what I actually got was a sequence of ints:

```
user=> (grid 2 2)
(0 1 0 1)
```

So my question is, how can I get the sequence I want? and, why did I get the particular sequence I got?

Comment: As an aside, this is a great place to use `for`. `(for [x (range rows), y (range columns)] (point x y))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `map`. In the way you wrote the inner `map` is not being called. You are just returning the result of `(range columns)`.

Try this:

```
(defn grid [rows columns]
  (mapcat (fn [x] 
            (map (fn [y] (point x y))
                 (range columns)))
          (range rows)))
```

You can also make the call to `point` like that: `#(point x %)`. Probably easier to read than the way you wrote.

Comment: Thanks, this is the 2nd time improper use of parenthesis has bitten me. I have to be a bit more careful.